# Подгрузка сообщений при прокрутке вниз на JavaScript (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php, mysql

Хочу реализовать пагинацию с помощью подгрузки сообщений к уже существующим. Но вот как это сделать? Весь инет в поиске решений разрыл - не нашел ничего подходящего.

При загрузке страницы загружается 10 первых сообщений: 
`SELECT * FROM msg WHERE user_post=1 ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 10`

Использую CodeIgniter. Таким образом, после обращения к базе, я вывожу в вид в цикле все 10 комментариев и каждое сообщение беру в div с id равным идентификатору из базы.

Нужно при прокрутке вниз - подгружать еще 10 сообщений. Но Как это реализовать на Jquery?

P.S. Хотелось бы посмотреть наброски кода. Суть реализации. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Беглый поиск в интернете [помог](http://php5lab.com/blog80.html). А [вот тут](http://php5lab.com/jquery/scrollup.html) демонстрация работы.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Действительно хороший пример.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scrollCounter = -100;

$('#scrollhistory').scroll( function (e) {
  scrollOffsetTop = $(divScrolling.firstElementChild).offset().top;
  // положение первого элемента относительно y
  if( scrollOffsetTop > scrollCounter){
    scrollCounter += -100;
    messageLoad (10);
  }
});
```