# Пагинатор как Вконтакте

Tags: запрос, ajax

Опускаемся вниз и на станицу идут ещё записи, поискал и так не нашел, помогите как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Гляньте тут: [Подгрузка сообщений при прокрутке вниз на JavaScript (Jquery)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/74968/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите как [здесь](http://www.jstoolbox.com/2009/04/18/realizaciya-beskonechnoj-prokrutki-na-jquery/) описано. Полагаю, это именно то, что Вам нужно.